# How to query for entities where term reference field <> value

Tags: 8, database

I'm trying to query for all entities where term reference field does not equal a certain value. For example:

```
  $query = $this->entityQuery->get('node');
  $query->condition('my_term_ref_field', '5', '<>');
  $results = $query->execute();
```

When debugging this I get no results, as it looks like it tries to inner join the field table. This doesn't work for nodes where someone didn't fill in the term reference field. Any thoughts on how I can do this?

Comment: There's a hack [here](http://disq.us/p/1430qgx) that might help

Comment: You should be able to use `notExists` and then that condition in an or condition.